# Codesys Wago CAN communication

Tags: plc, can-bus, codesys

I have connected a Wago PFC200 750-8204 between two Components which communicates via CAN bus in order to receive the messages and for further processing. My approach was to implement it in codesys 2.3 with the WagoCanLayer2_02.lib library but i fail with the readind the canbus.
The Code.

```
open(BAUDRATE := 500000 ,ENABLE := TRUE );
can11BitFrame(
CAN_ID:= 16#380,
CAN_BUFFER:= FALSE,
ENABLE:= TRUE,
READ_FRAME:= frame,
DATA=> data);
```

Have you any idea how i can solve this and have you code examples?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I have to answer (although it's probably too late anyway).

Assuming that the CAN interface is initialized and working and that your `can11BitFrame` is a `CAN_RX_11BIT_FRAME` instance, the following should work:

```
can11BitFrame(
    CAN_ID := 16#380,
    CAN_BUFFER := FALSE,
    CAN_PORT := 0,    (* not sure if this is really necessary here *)
    ENABLE := TRUE,
    READ_FRAME := frame);

data := can11BitFrame.DATA;
```

or maybe

```
IF can11BitFrame.error = CAN_RECEIVE_OK THEN
    data := can11BitFrame.DATA;
END_IF
```

And you have to set `frame` to `true` each time you want to read the message.

I have no idea if and how the `DATA => data` is supposed to work (I am using FUP here). As far as I know. in ST you have to execute the function block first and can then access the output parameters.